# Is there a way to create my own batch of images?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I built a convolutional neural network model and I want to test it using real live camera. For sure it will not work if I enter frame by frame because the input shape of CNN architecture does not match with a single frame. For example input of the network should be like this

```
(50000, 32, 32, 3)
```

but a single frame shape like this

```
(32, 32, 3)
```

so I want to know if there is a way to create a batch of frames, say take each 5 frames together, test them with the model then take the next 5 frames and so on? Or repeat each frame and put them together into a batch the make the testing. I don't know is this possible or is there a better way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
f0 = np.zeros((32, 32, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
f1 = np.zeros((32, 32, 3), dtype=np.uint8) + 1
f2 = np.zeros((32, 32, 3), dtype=np.uint8) + 2
f3 = np.zeros((32, 32, 3), dtype=np.uint8) + 3
f4 = np.zeros((32, 32, 3), dtype=np.uint8) + 4

arrayOfArrays = np.array([f0,f1,f2,f3,f4])

print(arrayOfArrays.shape)
(5,32,32,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be achieved with a custom dataset. Something like this.

```
class Live_Video_Dataset(Dataset):

def __init__(self, transform=None):
    self.transform = transform
    self.video_buffer = []
    self.video_buffer_length

    # Here fill the video buffer with fremes from the camera asyncronusly.

def __len__(self):
    return self.video_buffer_length

def __getitem__(self, idx):

    if video_buffer[idx] == None
        # Handle Exception
    else:
        sample = video_buffer[idx]
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample
```

Since you did not specify the ML framework you are using, I assumed that you are using PyTorch. But I think that the logic is clear, you can adapt it to any ML framework. Hope it helps. Good luck.